# Value of property Id must be of type String - Error in CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

I am using the below cloudformation template to create a targetgroup for NLB. While executing the cloudformation template I am getting the error "Value of property Id must be of type String" due to the lines *Targets:  - Id: !Ref InstanceID*. I have selected AWS::EC2::Instance::Id, as a list because want to associate more than one instances in this target group. Please anyone help me to understand where is the exact issue.

```
Parameters:
  InstanceID:
    Description: Please Select the Instance IDs
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Instance::Id>
    Description: Select Instance ID to associate it with the Target Group
  VPC:
    Description: The VPC to deploy to the target group
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
    ConstraintDescription: Select VPC ID for the Target Group

Resources:
    EC2TargetGroup:
      Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
      Properties:                                                     
        HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
        HealthCheckProtocol: TCP
        HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 10
        HealthyThresholdCount: 3        
        Name: NLBTargetGroupForEndpointService
        Port: 22
        Protocol: TCP        
        TargetType: instance
        Targets:
         - Id: !Ref InstanceID
        UnhealthyThresholdCount: 3
        VpcId: !Ref VPC
        Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: EC2TargetGroup
        - Key: Port
          Value: 22
        - Key: Protocol
          Value: TCP
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this as Targets is an object https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup-targetdescription.html.

You have to develop your own cloudformation macro or custom resource if you want dynamic population of Targets.

Comment: It throws error "Value of property Targets must be a list of objects" with the change "Targets: !Ref InstanceID".

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `!Ref InstanceID`, I think it gets multi-valued string instead of one InstanceId. You may try setting InstanceId parameter to String type.

Refer https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/multiple-values-list-parameter-cli/ which explains security groups Reference.